# Can i use C++ vectors in C code in VS2008

Tags: c++, c

i am running c code in vs2008. I was curious if i can mix this code with c++ code

Comment: I thought Visual Studio **only** has a C++ compiler anyway; it doesn't have a C compiler. So if your code compiles at all, then you're already fine.

Comment: @Kerrek SB : It's got a `/TC` flag. Not a perfect C mode, but reasonably close (IIRC it uses the common subset of C and C++)

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is yes. However, there are some nuances.

C++ generally supports a large subset of C. It means that you can almost anything available in C (such as functions, libraries etc) from C++ code. From this point you have two options, an easy one and a bit harder.

Option #1 - Use C++ compiler.

Just have your code treated as C++. Simply put - use C++ compiler.

Option #2 - Mix C and C++.

You can write your C code and compile it with C++ compiler. Use C-like C++ where you need to use C++ components. For example, you may have a setup similar to the following:

- head1.h - declarations of your C functions. For example:

  void foo1();
- header2.h - declarations of your C functions that intend to use C++ code.

  ```
  #ifdef __cplusplus
  extern "C" {
  #endif
      void foo2 ();
  #ifdef __cplusplus
  }
  #endif
  ```

And two source files, one C and one C++:

- source1.c

  ```
  #include "header1.h"
  #include "header2.h"

  void foo1 ()
  {
     foo2 (); /* Call a C function that uses C++ stuff */
  }
  ```
- source2.cpp

  ```
  #include <vector>
  #include "header2.h"

  #ifdef __cplusplus
  extern "C" {
  #endif

  void foo2 ()
  {
      std::vector<int> data;
      /// ... etc.
  }

  #ifdef __cplusplus
  }
  #endif
  ```

Of course, you will have to compile "cpp" files with C++ compiler (but you can still compile "c" files with C compiler) and link your program with standard C++ runtime.

The similar (but slightly more complicated) approach is used by Apple, for example. They mix C++ and Objective-C, calling the hybrid Objective-C++.

**UPDATE:**

If you opt for compiling C code as C++, I recommend you spend some time studying the differences between C and C++. There are cases when the code could be both legal C and C++, but produce different results. For example:

```
extern int T;

int main()
{
    struct T { int a; int b; };
    return sizeof(T) + sizeof('T');
}
```

If it is a C program then the correct answer is 8. In case of C++ the answer is 9. I have explained this in more details in my blog post [here](http://lazarenko.me/2013/04/15/c-and-cpp-are-different/).

Hope it helps. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you are compiling your code using C++ compiler as a C++ program then you can use `std::vector`.
If you are compiling your code using C compiler as a C program then you cannot.

This is because `std::vector` is a type defined by the C++ Standard, C Standard does not define any type as `std::vector`.

In simple words a C compiler does not understand what `std::vector` is.

Comment: Nitpick: The compiler is the same; it's only a mode switch to swap between C and C++. /Nitpick

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding the OP, I'll delete my comments.

Comment: @amit: Nevermind, I deleted mine as well. An happy ending. :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a switch to compile .c files as C++ (/TP) .  If you enable this, you can use the c as C++.  Beware that some c code will not compile as C++ without modification (mainly to do with type casting; c++ has stricter rules for this).

Answer (score 0):

If you are interfacing with some existing C library, then you of course can use C++. If you are compiling as C though, you won't be able to use any C++ features, such as `std::vector`.